# Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler does not catch DataFormatException, FileAlreadyExistsException and NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, multithreading, file, exception

In the program I am writing, I have a button that calls a method called extractVideo in a new thread. This method can throw the exceptions DataFormatException, FileAlreadyExistsException and NoSuchFileException, that I want to catch to show the user a specific message, depending on the exception.

I found that to catch exceptions in another thread, the best way was to use Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler(), with a specific exception handler. This is how I tried to implement it:

```java
@FXML void dlStart(ActionEvent event)
{
    Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler h = (Thread th, Throwable ex) -> 
    {
        System.out.println("Uncaught exception: " + ex.getClass());
    };

    Thread dlThread = new Thread(() ->
    {
        ExtractVideos_DlAppli.extract(addressfield.getText());
    });

    dlThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);
    dlThread.start();
}
```

However, this gives me an unreported exception for all three exceptions cited above, and I can't see to understand why.

Do you have any idea of the causes of that, or a suggestion on how to do catch these exceptions?

EDIT:

As it was asked, I add an excerpt of the code in ExtractVideos_DlAppli.extract, which is the function that throws the exception.

```java
public static boolean extract(String p_file) throws NoSuchFileException, FileAlreadyExistsException, DataFormatException
{
    List<Video> videoList;

    try
    {
        File f = new File(p_file);
        String folder = f.getParent();
        File dlFolder = new File(folder + "/Videos");

        //this can throw NoSuchFileException if the parent of the p_file not entered correctly, and we want to inform the user of that. 
        FileHandler missingVidHandler = new FileHandler(folder + "/VideosManquantes.log");
        SimpleFormatter missingCutFormatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        missingCutHandler.setFormatter(missingCutFormatter);
        cutInfoLogger.addHandler(missingCutHandler);

        if (dlFolder.isDirectory())
        {
            dlFolder.renameTo(new File(dlFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "_OLD"));
            //the idea is to throw the exception here to catch it and use it to inform the user of what is happening with their folder. There may be more elegant ways.
            throw new FileAlreadyExistsException(dlFolder.toString());
        }

        if (dlFolder.mkdir())
        {
            //the class videoDAO throws DataFormatException if it can't parse the file passed in p_file
            videoList = new videoDAO(f).getVideoList();

            for (Video currentVid: videoList)
            {
                currentVid.downloadVideo(dlFolder.toString());
                currentVid.makeSub(dlFolder.toString());
            }
        }

    }
    catch (SecurityException | IOException | IllegalArgumentException ex)
    {
        Logger errLogger = Logger.getLogger(ExtractVideos_DlAppli.class.getName()+"stopExecLogger");
        ConsoleHandler errHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        errHandler.setFormatter(defaultFormatter);
        errLogger.addHandler(errHandler);
        errLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't throw any exception. Can you provide a sample that actually shows the issue you've got?

Comment: Are the exceptions you mentioned captured inside dlThread ? Can you share the extract method code too ?

Comment: @Lothar I added the part of the extract method that throws those exceptions. Is it what you asked for>

Comment: @RajanSingh I don't capture the exceptions in the thread. All the dlThead do is calling the extract method. I added the code that throws the error in the extract method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code is already catching all the exceptions in catch block present in extract apart from the DataFormatException. Try removing the IoException from the catch clause so that it can propagate to the Uncaught exception handler you have provided to the thread. Add IoException to throws signature if you get compile warnings.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I thought specifying the exception would override the IOException catch... I was wrong in the end!

Comment: Yeah. It can be tricky sometimes to get your head around things. There is no wrong or right, it's a trajectory we all are in and will be. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score -1):

`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` is designed to be a thread's last-ditch effort at performing certain tasks (usually logging/reporting the exception) when all else goes south. It is NOT meant as a replacement for "proper" exception handing or a `throws` clause. 
To fix your error, you need to catch the exceptions:

```java
    Thread dlThread = new Thread(() ->
    {
        try {
            ExtractVideos_DlAppli.extract(addressfield.getText());
        } 
        catch(DataFormatException e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
        catch(FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
        catch(NoSuchFileException e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // Something else went wrong, handle it
        }
    });
```

EDIT: inside the `extract` method, you are catching `IOException`. All of the listed exceptions (possibly excluding `DataFormatException`) are subclasses of `IOException`. This results in them being caught here:

```java
...                            VVV
catch (SecurityException | IOException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {...}
```

[FileAlreadyExistsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileAlreadyExistsException.html)
[FileNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/NoSuchFileException.html)

Comment: I tried that previously, and it seems like the code never enters the catch: it is logged in the default logger, and stops. Nothing I write in the catch is ever executed.

Comment: Are you sure you're catching the right thing? This definitely works.

Comment: I just verified again (I had that code commented), and yes, that is the exception I am catching. I also tried adding the general catch (Exception e), and even that doesn't catch anything, It goes straight to the default handler.

Comment: Your catch clause inside the method catches `IOException`. All of the exceptions you listed as thrown (possibly excluding `DataFormatException`) are subclasses if it.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! I thought specifying the exception would override the IOException catch... I was wrong in the end!